# Why is the SelectionChanged signal triggered every time i click on the layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

i'm making some experiments with the **SelectionChanged** signal of a **QgsVectorLayer**.

i try this piece of code :

```
curLayer.selectionChanged.connect(self.test)
```

and "test" print a warning message.

The probleme i have is that the signal is triggered **every time i click on the layer**, even when there's no change of selection ...

Is there something i'm missing in this SelectionChanged behaviour ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then, after a few searches :

U got to use the two lists provided by the SelectionChanged signal :

```
QgsFeatureIds selected,QgsFeatureIds deselected (as mentionned in the API doc...)
```

to check what is really changing in your selection, of course multiple features selection is to take in account ...