# selectionChanged connection is being called twice

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I have this function with:
`self.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(self.openThePano)`

which waits for a feature selection change to connect to the function `openThePano` the issue is that once a single feature is selected the function is called twice and there is only one line that has this signal.

example code:

```
def actualapp(self):
    #waits for the signal
    self.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(self.openThePano)

def openThePano(self,fId):
    #gets the feature's attributes
    featget = fId.selectedFeatures()
    atributos = [i.attributes() for i in featget]

    source = ogr.Open(self.shproute)
    layer = source.GetLayer() 
    schema = [] 
    ldef = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for n in range(ldef.GetFieldCount()): # gets the attributes' names
        fdef = ldef.GetFieldDefn(n)
        schema.append(fdef.name)

    # This loop prints attributes of the selected feature and is being printed twice.
    for i in range(len(atributos[0])): 
        print('{}: {}'.format(str(schema[i]),str(atributos[0][i])))

    self.iface.actionZoomToSelected().trigger()
```

I expect it to only print once the list of attributes but for some reason I ignore it does it twice, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue in the past : i think the signal is triggered **when the selection changes** that means (if u make *one by one* feature selections ...) that the signal is triggered when your previous feature is deselected **AND** your next feature is selected ...

The case of **multiple feature selection** must be handled by your code too ...

See [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109189/why-is-the-selectionchanged-signal-triggered-every-time-i-click-on-the-layer) and api doc of course ...

Comment: I am not sure I understand, I saw docs and your post, you are saying that it is being printed twice because it is calling both signals, the deselection and the selection? I also saw a Parameter called "clearAndSelect" but I am not sure how to call it because it tells me that doesn't exist. @snaileater

Comment: tried this out: `self.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged(clearAndSelect=True).connect(self.openThePano)` and gave `native Qt Signal is not callable` I would appreciate any help you could provide.