# What signal can be used to get the selection change on a feature?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

Right now I am using:

`self.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(FunctionThatReactsToTheSignal)`

But this one sends two signals, one for the deselection of the previous feature and one for te selection of the new one, so the `FunctionThatReactsToTheSignal` is executed twice, is there a way to make it send just one signal for the new selection or another signal function to avoid repetitions?

Comment: That signal is only called once. Are you sure you are doing the connect only once?

Comment: yes, it is the first thing I checked, but the function is being called twice per signal. @FranRaga

Comment: What is your version of qgis?

Comment: 3.4.7-Madeira @FranRaga

Comment: mmm.. is so strange then,only called once using this version

Comment: That is what I think but it is doing this, so i previously asked here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322909/selectionchanged-connection-is-being-called-twice/322966#322966 and someone answer that both signals are presented but I didn't understand how to control these signals since I can barely make sense of qgis documentations.

Comment: In 3.28 Ferenze the selectionChanged method still sends two signals.